# Prove an algorithm for logarithmic mean $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n=\frac{a_0-b_0}{\ln a_0-\ln b_0}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, logarithms, recurrence-relations, means

Take:

$$a_0=x,~~~~b_0=y$$

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+\sqrt{a_nb_n}}{2},~~~~b_{n+1}=\frac{b_n+\sqrt{a_nb_n}}{2}$$

Then we obtain as a limit the logarithmic mean of $x,y$:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n=\frac{x-y}{\ln x-\ln y}$$

**I don't know how to prove this.** But I do know that numerically it fits really well.

In fact, the best approximation is obtained if we take geometric mean of $a_n,b_n$:

$$x=5,~~~~y=3$$

$$\begin{array}( n & \sqrt{a_nb_n} & \frac{x-y}{\ln x-\ln y} \\ 4 & \color{blue}{3.915}0640985032 & 3.9152303779424 \\ 10 & \color{blue}{3.915230}33734566 & 3.9152303779424 \\ 20 & \color{blue}{3.9152303779424} & 3.9152303779424  \end{array}$$

The convergence rate can be approximated by:

$$\frac{a_{n+1}-b_{n+1}}{a_n-b_n}=\frac{1}{2}$$

This seems like a very simple way to compute logarithms, for example:

$$x=2,~~~~y=1$$

$$\ln2=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_nb_n}}$$

> How do I prove that the limit of this sequence is really the logarithmic mean?

---

**Edit**

It turns out this algorithm is mentioned in (at least) two papers by B. C. Carlson as early as 1971:

https://www.jstor.org/stable/2317088

https://www.jstor.org/stable/2317754

Still, if someone can provide their own proof, I would be grateful.

Comment: Similar sequence: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean I bet one can solve it in a similar fashion, i.e. find some elliptic (or similar) integral that has the property that $I(x,y) = I(x + \sqrt{xy}/2, y + \sqrt{xy}/2)$.

Comment: @Winther,  there are at least three integral forms for the logarithmic mean, so yes

Comment: I'd simply prove that the logarithmic mean of $a_{n+1}$ and $b_{n+1}$ is the same as that of $a_n$ and $b_n$.

Comment: @IvanNeretin, seems sensible, thank you for the idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several exact identities, such as
$$
a_{n+1}-b_{n+1}=\frac{a_n-b_n}2\implies a_n-b_n=2^{-n}(a_0-b_0),
\\
\frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}}=\sqrt{\frac{a_n}{b_n}}\implies
\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\left(\frac{a_0}{b_0}\right)^{2^{-n}}
$$
The first tells us that if one of the sequences has a limit the other has the some limit. In combination $b_n$ can be eliminated to get, via mean value theorem, or $N(\sqrt[N]x-1)\to \ln x$ for $N\to \infty$,
$$
a_n=\frac{2^{-n}(a_0-b_0)}{1-\left(\frac{b_0}{a_0}\right)^{2^{-n}}}
=\frac{a_0-b_0}{\ln a_0-\ln b_0+O(2^{-n})}
$$